# I'm learning Redux and In the below application I'm Not getting "listings" in App.js. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux. Here I tried to build a simple app to understand the concept. Why can't I get listings in App.js? I've passed it from index.js through dispatch and I'm trying to receive it in useEffect in App.js.

**index.js**

I'm passing mockData as listings from index.js to App.js

```
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

const mockData = [
  {
      name: "Barry Johnson",
      age: 43,
  },
  {
      name: "Chris Evan",
      age: 25,
  },
];
const getAll = () => {
  return mockData;
};

const listingsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'INIT_LISTINGS':
          return action.data;
      default:
          return state;
  }
};
export const initListings = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
     const listings = await getAll();
     dispatch({
         type: 'INIT_LISTINGS',
         data: listings,
     });
  };
};

const store = createStore(listingsReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js**

Here inside useEffect where I'm logging listings, I'm getting undefined.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { initListings } from './index.js';

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const listings = useSelector((state) => state.listings)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(initListings());
    console.log(listings);
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your reducer function use this listings is your reducer function :-

```
const listingsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case 'INIT_LISTINGS':
          return {...state, listings : action.payload};
      default:
          return state;
  }
};
```